# How to show tree navigation menu in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, tree, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I'm a newbie in scala. I am trying to build navigation tree like

- Parent

  - Child1
  - Child2
  - Child3
  - Child4

I have a model class for it.

```
case class Field(id:Long, name:String, icon:String, parentid:Long)

object Field {
  def all():List[Field] = {
    List(
      Field(1,"Parent1","1", 0),
      Field(2,"Child1","2",1),
      Field(3,"Child2","3",1),
      Field(4,"Child3","4",1),
      Field(5,"Child4","5",1)
    )
  }
}
```

And in my view I have a code for rendering:

```
@fields.groupBy(_.parentid).map {  case ( parentid, tasks) =>
<ul>
    <li>@parentid</li>
    <ul>
        @tasks.map { task =>
            <li>@task.name</li>
        }
    </ul>
</ul>
}
```

But unfortunately the output is:

- 1

  - Child1
  - Child2
  - Child3
  - Child4
- 0

  - Parent1

How to build navigation menu, where model has child/parent relationship?
I hope you understand my question, and will help me. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be quite tricky to convert the structure that you have to a tree. You would need to define another type to represent a tree node, and you would need a recursive function to process your list of `Field`.

I suggest the following structure instead:

```
case class TreeNode(name: String, icon: String, children: TreeNode*)

object Menu {
  val tree = TreeNode("parent", "0",
    TreeNode("child1", "1"),
    TreeNode("child2", "2"),
    TreeNode("child3", "3",
      TreeNode("grandchild1", "4"))
   )
}
```

You will need a recursive function ("code block" in a template) to render it:

```
@renderNode(n: TreeNode) = {
  <li>@n.name</li>
  @if(!n.children.isEmpty) {
    <ul>
      @for(c <- n.children) {
        @renderNode(c)
      }
    </ul>
  }
}

<ul>
   @renderNode(Menu.tree)
</ul>
```

I haven't tried recursive code blocks in a Play template, so I have no idea if this will work!